# Disable button based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Button :

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=initiate_call("'.$persons['pk_id'].'","'.$persons['mobile_no'].'");>
```

Javascript:

```
function initiate_call(pk_id,number){       
    $('button[value=\'"'+pk_id+'","'+number+'"\']').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

My java script not disabling any button.but i need to disable only  particular button.

How this can be using javascript or jquery.

Comment: `$('button[value="val"]').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Give the button an ID and use that instead.

Comment: You can use `eq()` with index

Comment: i tried this **$('button[value="'+pk_id+'","'+number+'"]').prop('disabled', true);**.it says : Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button[value="6","8737827319"]

Comment: @Kiranarya ADD resulting HTML with complete code.

Comment: try $('button[value="'+pk_id+number+'"]').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: not sure but you can try $("buttonID/buttonClass").prop('disable',true'). Or use .css() to change the css style of it

Comment: what a value in button should be??

Comment: I said _"ADD resulting HTML with complete code"_

Comment: @Kiranarya `$('button[value=\'"'+pk_id+'","'+number+'"\']')` , in your case you need to wrap the attribute value within quotes

Comment: @PranavCBalan - i tried but no change.it is not giving any error but not working .

Comment: @Kiranarya : can you add code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: my question is simple why downvoting ??. i m just passing two value in onclick and want to disable button based on those two values.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - check http://jsfiddle.net/z8frkndu/3/

Comment: @Kiranarya : currently the button value is `click me`

Comment: @PranavCBalan - done. thanks a lot.my mistake

Comment: In your fiddle, you need to change it from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`.  The selector that the initiate function would use in that example is `button[value='"16","8745853113"']`.  Since your button value is "8745853113", that selector returns no objects, so nothing is affected.